# Handle when api doesn't respond

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, currency

I am trying to get euro, dollar and turkish liras currencies and comparing them. But sometimes api (i am using a random currency website json values) can't respond. 
Cannot get any value and page loading 30 sec, after execute time was done, error appears. 
What i am trying to do is: if it couldn't get any value in 1 second(or less) from api, return null. How can i do that. If anybody can help, i would glad. This is my php codes. I was tried to use if else in this, but can't worked.

ps: I have a ajax codes for that, its refreshing when the value are change. This is working most times. But 2-3 times in a day, it throws error.

```
$json_eur = file_get_contents('https://doviz.com/api/v1/currencies/EUR/latest');
$val_eur = json_decode($json_eur, true);

echo $val_eur['selling'];
```

**EDIT**

This is the solve. Added some codes to JRoss answer.

```
$ctx_dollar = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 1
    )
)
);
$usd_url = 'https://doviz.com/api/v1/currencies/USD/latest';

if (@file_get_contents($usd_url)):
    $json_usd = file_get_contents($usd_url, 0, $ctx_dollar);
    $val_usd = json_decode($json_usd, true);
    if (is_numeric($val_usd['selling'])) {
        echo $val_usd['selling'];
    }
    else {
        echo "loading...";
    }
endif;
```

Comment: You need to check if data is not respond back are they give any error message in response if they give then make check accoding to that if they not then you have to check conditions checking options like is_array or count($val_eur)

Comment: Use curl. It's much more configurable, such as setting timeouts.

Comment: This issue was occurs when no one can access website. When error throwed i can't get in website too. This is about "doviz.com". But is there any way to handle with it?

Comment: if they are not giving any response at that time $val_eur will be an empty array then do checking if(count($val_eur)>0 && is_array($val_eur)){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 1 
        ) 
    ) 
); 
file_get_contents("https://doviz.com/api/v1/currencies/EUR/latest", 0, $ctx);
```

http://php.net/file_get_contents

and on top of that I would catch exceptions. `try {} catch (Exception $e) {}`

Comment: That worked with try catch. But i need to add something else too.
if (@file_get_contents($usd_url)): is controll if url exist. i am updating my question right now.